# Memory leak suspicion in realloc () function

Tags: c++

I need Yours help!

Need to solve a task:

User type an float array A. Need to copy positive values to array B, negative - to array C.

I wrote code for this task:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "stdlib.h"


using namespace std;


int main ()
{
int n;            //number of array A elements
int m=1, l=1;     //number of Array B and C correspondly

cout<<"Please enter n: ";
cin>>n;                                       //number input

float *A = (float *) malloc (n*sizeof(float));//dynamic array A definition

for (int i=0;i<n;i++)                         //array A filling
{
cout<<"Please enter A["<<i<<"]= ";
cin>>A[i];
}

float *B = (float *) malloc (m*sizeof(float));//Array B definition with 1 element for beginning
float *C = (float *) malloc (l*sizeof(float));//Array C definition with 1 element for beginning

for (int i=0;i<n;i++)
{
if(A[i]!=0)
    {
    if(A[i]>0) 
        {
        B[m-1] = A[i];
        B = (float *) realloc (B, (m++)*sizeof(float));
        }
    else
        {
        C[l-1] = A[i];
        C = (float *) realloc (C, (l++)*sizeof(float));
        }
    }

}
if(m>2) B = (float *) realloc (B, (m--)*sizeof(float)); //because arrays created with 1 extra elements
if(l>2) C = (float *) realloc (C, (l--)*sizeof(float)); //need delete last element that doesn`t have a number

for (int i=0;i<n;i++)
{
cout<<"A["<<i<<"]= "<<A[i]<<endl;
}

free(A);

cout<<endl;

for (int i=0;i<m;i++)
{
cout<<"B["<<i<<"]= "<<B[i]<<endl;
}

free(B);

cout<<endl;

for (int i=0;i<l;i++)
{
cout<<"C["<<i<<"]= "<<C[i]<<endl;
}

cout<<endl;

free(C);


return 0;
}
```

But problem, that program works, only when, user type less that 4 positive and negative values:

```
A[6]={1,2,3, -1,-2,-3} //work correctly
A[7]={1,2,3,0,-1,-2,-3} //work correctly
A[8]={1,2,3,0,0,-1,-2,-3} //work correctly

A[7]={1,2,3,4,-1,-2,-3} //not work
or
A[7]={1,2,3,-4,-1,-2,-3} //not work
A[8]={1,2,3,4,-5,-1,-2,-3} //not work
```

Error:

```
*** Error in `./main': realloc(): invalid next size: 0x08f84278 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x67257)[0xb7432257]
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x6d577)[0xb7438577]
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x70410)[0xb743b410]
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(realloc+0x10e)[0xb743c53e]
./main[0x8048a1b]
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf7)[0xb73e3637]
./main[0x80487b1]
======= Memory map: ========
08048000-08049000 r-xp 00000000 fd:01 399768     /home/work/Desktop/New Folder/main
0804a000-0804b000 r--p 00001000 fd:01 399768     /home/work/Desktop/New Folder/main
0804b000-0804c000 rw-p 00002000 fd:01 399768     /home/work/Desktop/New Folder/main
08f7f000-08fa4000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0          [heap]
b7200000-b7221000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b7221000-b7300000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
b7357000-b7359000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b7359000-b7375000 r-xp 00000000 fd:01 391774     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
b7375000-b7376000 rw-p 0001b000 fd:01 391774     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
b7376000-b73c9000 r-xp 00000000 fd:01 391722     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libm-2.23.so
b73c9000-b73ca000 r--p 00052000 fd:01 391722     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libm-2.23.so
b73ca000-b73cb000 rw-p 00053000 fd:01 391722     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libm-2.23.so
b73cb000-b757a000 r-xp 00000000 fd:01 391744     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc-2.23.so
b757a000-b757b000 ---p 001af000 fd:01 391744     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc-2.23.so
b757b000-b757d000 r--p 001af000 fd:01 391744     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc-2.23.so
b757d000-b757e000 rw-p 001b1000 fd:01 391744     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc-2.23.so
b757e000-b7581000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b7581000-b76ee000 r-xp 00000000 fd:01 915714     /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.21
b76ee000-b76ef000 ---p 0016d000 fd:01 915714     /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.21
b76ef000-b76f4000 r--p 0016d000 fd:01 915714     /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.21
b76f4000-b76f5000 rw-p 00172000 fd:01 915714     /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.21
b76f5000-b76f8000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b770c000-b770f000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b770f000-b7711000 r--p 00000000 00:00 0          [vvar]
b7711000-b7712000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0          [vdso]
b7712000-b7734000 r-xp 00000000 fd:01 391726     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/ld-2.23.so
b7734000-b7735000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b7735000-b7736000 r--p 00022000 fd:01 391726     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/ld-2.23.so
b7736000-b7737000 rw-p 00023000 fd:01 391726     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/ld-2.23.so
bfec6000-bfee7000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0          [stack]
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Problem code block:

```
for (int i=0;i<n;i++)
{
if(A[i]!=0)
    {
    if(A[i]>0) 
        {
        B[m-1] = A[i];
        B = (float *) realloc (B, (m++)*sizeof(float));
        }
    else
        {
        C[l-1] = A[i];
        C = (float *) realloc (C, (l++)*sizeof(float));
        }
    }

}
```

**Maybe i don`t correct use realloc?**

Comment: Why are you using `malloc` and `realloc` here? Whenever you need a "dynamic array" in C++ then you should be using `std::vector`.

Comment: As for one possible cause of your problems, `(m++)*sizeof(float)` increase `m` *after* it has been used. Try instead `++m * sizeof(float)`. That means your reallocation is for the same amount as before, but `m` and `l` will not reflect that.

Comment: Sorry, but why i can`t use realloc? It purpose is memory reallocation according to adding (with saving values in array) and deleting elements, or no?

Comment: Lastly, you don'y have a memory leak. The message  "Error in './main': realloc(): invalid next size..." means you go out of bounds of some memory you have allocated. Like could happen if the reallocation doesn't allocate enough. Also, remember that `realloc` can return a null pointer, leading to a possible actual memory leak, and definitely *undefined behavior* if you forget to check for it.

Comment: I agree with @Someprogrammerdude, or try by first increment m `m += 1` and then allocate memory.

Comment: `(m++)*sizeof(float)` Helped, program correct works thanks a lot! Last question, what do You think. what is reason, that this error is seable only, when users type more than 3 (program work in case less than 4), positive or negative values.Unless going beyond the array should happen already on the second iteration of the loop?

Comment: @WhiteBear Accessing outside an array causes undefined behavior, which means anything can happen. It might cause an error, it might not.